# What is time complexity of recursive level order traversal of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, time-complexity

In [THIS](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/) geeksforgeeks link they are describing the time complexity of recursive level order traversal as `O(n^2)`.

Time Complexity: `O(n^2)` in worst case. For a skewed tree, `printGivenLevel()` takes `O(n)` time where n is the number of nodes in the skewed tree. So time complexity of `printLevelOrder()` is `O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + .. + O(1)` which is `O(n^2)`.This is not clear to me.

Can someone please help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a skewed tree like this:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
   ...
     \
      N
```

The depth of this tree is N, so the below function will run from 1 to N,

```
printLevelorder(tree)
for d = 1 to height(tree)
   printGivenLevel(tree, d);
```

That is,

```
printGivenLevel(tree, 1);
printGivenLevel(tree, 2);
...
printGivenLevel(tree, N);
```

And `printGivenLevel(tree, depth)` takes O(depth) time since it begins from the root every time.

The time complexity is:

```
O(1) + O(2) + ... + O(N) = O(N^2)
```

Comment: BTW, make sure you use a queue to implement BFS algorithm in O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Notice that this is an arithmetic progression. [We know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) that it will sum as follows:

```
n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1 = n * (n - 1) / 2
```

But:

```
n * (n - 1) / 2 = (n^2 - n) / 2
```

However, [we know](http://discrete.gr/complexity/) that the quadratic (squared) term **dominates** the expression compared to the linear term and that the `1 / 2` is a constant factor, both of which simplify the expression as follows:

First, drop the constant factor:

```
O((n^2 - n) / 2) = O(n^2 - n)
```

Next, keep the dominant term:

```
O(n^2 - n) = O(n^2)
```

This is how you arrive at this complexity.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. My question was not about AP sum but where this equation came from and how about the for loop which run from 1 to the height of the tree (which will be n in worst case) inside which printlevel is called. so two doubts 1. Should not it be O(n) * time complexity of printlevel  2. where does this expression comes from from time complexity of printlevel (O)(n) + O(n-1) ...